# Reduce height of a DIV from top

Tags: html, css

I have a DIV that lays over a YouTube video iframe.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ym5w8/42/

What I'm trying to do is reduce height of overlay `DIV (.the-box)` from top of it.

For a example, like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Ym5w8/43/

I know that I can just set height from the bottom but NO, what I'm trying to do is reduce height from top to bottom.

Let's say I want to reduce size of the overlay DIV from `300px` ( means YouTube video will be clearly visible 300px from top to bottom. )

```
__________________________
|         |               |
|         |               |
|         | 300px visible |
|         |               |
|        \/               |                    
|                         |
|  rest is still covered  |
|________________________ |
```

It could be any amount, 300px, 200px, 50px. I'll be inserting the amount to CSS source from database.

```
.the-box { 
    reduce-from-top: <?php echo $size ?>px; 
    position: absolute; 
    left: 0px; 
    right: 0px; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 100%; 
    z-index: 999; 
    background-color: white; 
    opacity: 0.5; 
}
```

Comment: Set bottom css. Then it will.be pinned to the bottom off the area instead off the top

Comment: Come again, what do you want to achieve  in http://jsfiddle.net/Ym5w8/43/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured the answer myself.

Just set the height to `auto` and set `top` the size you want to reduce.

```
.the-click { 
  position: absolute; 
  left: 0px; 
  right: 0px; 
  bottom: 0; 
  top: 100px; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: auto; 
  z-index: 999; 
  background-color: white; 
  opacity: 0.5;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Ym5w8/46/

Hope this helps someone else. :)

Answer (score 2):

Setting `overflow:hidden` on the parent and using a `top` position value would seem to be what you require.

```css
.the-click {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  top: 100px;
  /* this is the arbitrary value */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 999;
  background-color: red;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.the-click:hover {
  background-color:#bada55; 
  }
.container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* stops the overlay from expanding beyond the container */
}
iframe {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div align="center" class="container">
  <a href="http://thelink" class="the-click"></a>

  <iframe wmode="Opaque" class="video-iframe" width="100%" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/ZauRZNs8BMg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen=""></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [flexbox layout](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)! On container, set `display: flex` and `align-items: flex-end`, then set your CSS on the inner div as you normally would. The `flex-end` value makes it stick to the bottom of its container.

```css
div.outer {
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
}

div.inner {
  background-color: pink;
  height: 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```